# Proof of Exercise 4.3 from Isaac's "Character Theory of Finite Groups"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I am trying to prove the following statement.

> Let $G = H \times K$. Let $\varphi \in Irr(H)$ and $\theta \in Irr(K)$ be faithful. Show that $\varphi \times \theta$ is faithful iff $(|Z(H)| ,|Z(K)|)=1$.

I know that various solutions to this issue have been proposed. But I don't fully understand how to prove this statement from right to left.

I took some hints from Derek Holt. I got the following reasoning, which I can't fully implement.

Due to the fact that $\varphi, \theta$ are faithful irreducible characters, we understand that $Z(\varphi) = Z(H); Z(\theta) = Z(K).$

Consider $h\in H\setminus Z(H)$. It is clear that with an irreducible representation, a scalar matrix will not correspond to it, which means $|\varphi(h)| < \varphi(1).$ The last inequality is a mixture of the triangle inequality and a very well-known fact.

$\textbf{Fact:}$ Let $\varepsilon_1, \ldots, \varepsilon_n \in\mathbb{C}$ be the roots of unity. Then $$|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\varepsilon_i|= n\Rightarrow\forall\; i = 1, \ldots, n\Rightarrow\varepsilon_i = \lambda\; (|\lambda|= 1).$$

Similar reasoning can be carried out with $K$.

Let $\chi = \varphi \times \theta$. Taking into account the above facts, we get that $$\chi(hk) = \varphi(h)\theta(k) = \chi(1) = \varphi(1)\theta(1),$$ if $h\in Z(H); k\in Z(K)$.

However, I do not understand how this proof can be completed from here. Perhaps it's quite simple, so I apologize in advance for not being able to see obvious ways to solve this problem.

Any help?

$\textbf{UPD:}$

As I understand it, the whole idea of the proof should come down to the fact that if $h\neq 1; k\neq 1$ then $|h| =|k|$. However, this is not the case due to the fact that $(|Z(H)|, |Z(K)|) = 1.$

Let $h = 1$ and $k\neq 1$. Then $$\chi(hk) = \chi(k) = \varphi(1)\theta(k) = \chi(1) = \varphi(1)\theta(1) \Rightarrow \theta(k) = \theta(1)$$

But this is not possible, since $\theta$ is faithful character. Similar reasoning can be carried out with $k = 1.$

But why $|h| = |k|$ in other cases?

$\textbf{In my reasoning, I refer to this:}$ [$\phi \times \theta$ is faithful iff $(|Z(H)| ,|Z(K)|)=1$ for faithful characters $\phi \in Irr(H)$ and $\theta \in Irr(K)$ .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430839/phi-times-theta-is-faithful-iff-zh-zk-1-for-faithful-character?noredirect=1&lq=1)

$\textbf{UPD:}$ I may have figured out why this is the case. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Let $n = |h|\neq|k|$; and $hk \in \ker(\varphi \times \theta) \subseteq Z(\varphi \times \theta) = Z(H) \times Z(K).$  Then $$\chi(h^nk^n) = \varphi(h^n)\theta(k^n) = \varphi(1)\theta(k^n) = \varphi(1)\theta(1) \Rightarrow \theta(k^n) = \theta(1)$$

But this is not possible, since $\theta$ is faithful character.

Comment: Where did you get these hints? From another post? I don't think the implication '$(|Z(H)|, |Z(K)|) = 1 \Rightarrow Z(H)\times Z(K)$ is cyclic' is true without further hypotheses. For instance, take $H = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $K = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Also, what does $Z(\varphi)$ mean? $\ker(\varphi)$?

Comment: Or does $Z(H)$ denote the centralizer of $H$ inside $G$, rather than the center of $H$?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, it's my mistake. This reasoning was valid when proving in the other direction. I have already corrected this point in the proof.

Comment: $Z(\varphi) = \lbrace g \in G \; | \; |\varphi(g)| = \varphi(1) \rbrace$

Answer (score 1):

The statement in the book of Isaacs is wrong. It should be as follows.

> **Proposition** Let $G=H \times K$. Let $\varphi \in Irr(H)$ and $\vartheta \in Irr(K)$. Then the following hold.
> $(a)$If  $\varphi \times \vartheta$ is faithful, then $\varphi$ and $\vartheta$ are faithful.
> $(b)$ If $Z(G)=1$ and $\varphi$ and $\vartheta$ are faithful, then $\varphi \times \vartheta$ is faithful.

Note that if we drop $G$ to be centerless in $(b)$, the proposition is not true, $G=C_2 \times C_2$ has no faithful irreducible character. 
Before proceeding with the proof of this proposition, we need a number-theoretical lemma.

> **Lemma 1** Let $e, f$ be natural numbers and  $\epsilon_1, \cdots, \epsilon_e \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\zeta_1, ..\cdots, \zeta_f \in \mathbb{C}$ be roots of unity. Then the following hold.
> $(a)$ $\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e=e$ if and only if $\epsilon_i=1$ for all $i=1, \cdots, e$.
> $(b)$ $|\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e|=e$ if and only if $\epsilon_i=\epsilon$ for all $i=1, \cdots, e$.
> $(c)$ $(\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e)\cdot(\zeta_1 + \cdots + \zeta_f)=ef$ if and only if $\epsilon_i=\epsilon$ for all $i=1, \cdots e$ and $\zeta_j=\zeta=\epsilon^{-1}$ for all $j=1, \cdots, f$.
> $(d)$ $|\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e|\cdot |\zeta_1 + \cdots + \zeta_f|=ef$ if and only if $\epsilon_i=\epsilon$ for all $i=1, \cdots e$ and $\zeta_j=\zeta$ for all $j=1, \cdots, f$.

**Proof** For all statements $(a)$, $(b)$, $(c)$ and $(d)$ we only have to prove the "only if" side.

(a) Put $\alpha_i=Re(\epsilon_i)$. Then $|\alpha_i| \leq 1$ and  $\alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_e=e$. Assume that for some $i$ we have $|\alpha_i| \lt 1$. Then $e=|e|=|\alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_e| \leq |\alpha_1| + \cdots + |\alpha_e| \lt e$, a contradiction. Hence, $|\alpha_i|=1$ for all $i$, that is, $\alpha_i \in \{-1,1\}$. But $\sum_{i=1}^f \alpha_i = e$, this can only be the case if $\alpha_i=1$ for all $i$, implying $\epsilon_i=1$ for all $i$.

(b) Induction on $e$. First have a look at $e=2$. Hence $|\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2|=2$. Put $\lambda=\frac {\epsilon_2}{\epsilon_1}$, then, since $|\epsilon_1|=1$, we have $|1+\lambda|=2$, and $|\lambda|=1$, since also $|\epsilon_2|=1$. So $(1+\lambda)(1+\overline{\lambda})=4$, which amounts to $\lambda + \overline{\lambda}=2$. So by (a), we have $\lambda=1$, whence $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2$. For the induction step, assume $|\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e|=e$. But then $f=|\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e| \leq |\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_{e-1}| + |\epsilon_e| \leq |\epsilon_1| + \cdots + |\epsilon_{e-1}| + |\epsilon_e|=e$. It follows that $|\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_{e-1}|=e-1$. By induction $\epsilon_1= ... =\epsilon_{e-1}$. Now apply the previous induction step on $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2, \cdots, \epsilon_e$, which gives $\epsilon_2= ... =\epsilon_{e}$ and combine the two conclusions, which gives that all the $\epsilon_i$'s are equal.

(c) Assume $(\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e)\cdot(\zeta_1 + \cdots + \zeta_f)=ef$. Then $ef=|(\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e)\cdot(\zeta_1 + \cdots + \zeta_f)| =|\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e|\cdot|\zeta_1 + \cdots + \zeta_f| \leq |\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e|\cdot f$, whence $e \leq |\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e|$. But of course $|\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e| \leq e$, so we have equality and we can apply (b). It follows that $e\epsilon(\zeta_1 + \cdots + \zeta_f)=ef$, so $\zeta_1 + \cdots + \zeta_f=\epsilon^{-1}f$. Taking absolute values and applying (b) finishes the proof.

(d) Let $|\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e|\cdot|\zeta_1 + \cdots + \zeta_f|=ef$. Then $ef=|\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e|\cdot|\zeta_1 + \cdots + \zeta_f| \leq |\epsilon_1 + \cdots + \epsilon_e|\cdot f$. Now follow the same reasoning as in (c). $\square$

> **Lemma 2** Let $G=H \times K$. Let $\varphi \in Irr(H)$ and $\vartheta \in Irr(K)$. Then we have the inclusions:
> $$ker(\varphi) \times ker(\vartheta) \subseteq ker(\varphi \times \vartheta) \subseteq Z(\varphi) \times Z(\vartheta)=Z(\varphi \times \vartheta).$$

**Proof** The first inclusion is trivial. Let $h \in H$ and $k \in K$, and assume $hk \in ker(\varphi \times \vartheta)$, so $(\varphi \times \vartheta)(hk)=\varphi(h)\vartheta(k)=(\varphi \times \vartheta)(1)=\varphi(1)\vartheta(1)$. Since both $\varphi(h)$ and $\vartheta(k)$ are sums of $\varphi(1)$ and $\vartheta(1)$ roots of unity respectively (see (2.15)(c) in Isaacs' book), we can apply Lemma 1(c) above. Hence $\varphi(h)=\epsilon\varphi(1)$  and $\vartheta(k)=\epsilon^{-1}\vartheta(1)$ for some root of unity $\epsilon$. Hence $h \in Z(\varphi)$ and also $k \in Z(\vartheta)$. 
It is clear that $Z(\varphi) \times Z(\vartheta) \subseteq Z(\varphi \times \vartheta)$, and the inverse inclusion is established by applying Lemma 1(d).$\square$

**Remark** In general for a $\chi \in Irr(G)$, we have $Z(G/ker(\chi))=Z(\chi)/ker(\chi)$, see Isaacs' book (2.27)Lemma(f). It follows that [$Z(G)=1$ and $\chi$ is faithful] if and only if $Z(\chi)=1$.

Now we are ready to prove the proposition.

(a) Let $h \in H$ and suppose that $h \in ker(\varphi)$, so $\varphi(h)=\varphi(1)$. Then $(\varphi \times \vartheta)(h)=(\varphi \times \vartheta)(h \cdot 1)=\varphi(h)\vartheta(1)=\varphi(1)\vartheta(1)$. So $h \in ker(\varphi \times \vartheta)=1$. Similarly, one shows that $\vartheta$ is faithful. Alternatively, apply Lemma 2, first inclusion.
(b)Assume that $Z(G)=1$ and both $\varphi$ and $\vartheta$ are faithful. Hence $Z(H)=1=Z(K)$ and the Remark above implies $Z(\varphi)=1=Z(\vartheta)$. From Lemma 2 it follows that $ker(\varphi \times \vartheta)=1$, whence $\varphi \times \vartheta$ is faithful.$\square$

**Final observation** In case of Proposition(a), $Z(G)$ must be cyclic and also $Z(H)$ and $Z(K)$ must be cyclic (see also (2.32) Theorem (a) in Isaacs' book)). This can only occur when gcd($|Z(H)|,|Z(K)|)=1$.

Comment: I don't quite understand why the condition of this problem is violated in the case of $C_2\times C_2$. 

$C_2\times C_2$, as you said, doesn't have faitful irreducible characters, but at the same time $(Z(C_2), Z(C_2)) \neq 1$. So, unfortunately, I don't see a contradiction.

Comment: Well, I intended to express the following, the Proposition (b) above is not true without the premise that $G$ is centerless. The non-trivial linear character of $C_2$ is faithful, but $C_2 \times C_2$ does not have any faithful characters.

Comment: Well, I realized that the statement (b) that you wrote is incorrect if $Z(G) \neq 1$. But I still don't understand why Isaacs' statement is wrong. What did you mean by that?

Comment: Does my final observation above help here?

Comment: To prove statement (a), I used these arguments.  But how to prove my statement in the opposite direction.  This is what caused me difficulty.

Comment: @NickyHekster I am also a little confused by this discussion. Are you saying that the statement that Mr Nobody is trying to prove, which is Exercise 4.3 in Isaacs' book,  is wrong? If so, what is your counterexample? $C_2 \times C_2$ is not a counterexample to that statement.

Comment: The $C_2 \times C_2$ is a counterexample, **not** to Isaacs' exercise, but to my proposition. I once had seen that the Exercise was wrongly stated but I cannot find the reference ... it seems to be all right after all, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253685/problem-4-3-i-martin-isaacs-character-theory . I do apologise for the confusion.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think I have brought the solution of this problem to the end. Could you please see how true my final idea is?